# Where clause only for part of the view

Tags: php, date, view, mariadb, where-clause

With help from @forpas I have this query: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=032295ff0b6e789102a42764cbe4dd3b)

The column ROWdifferencesALWAYS counts the amount of rows between the last row and the last time it occurred. Totally independent from the column 'date'.

I added the column ROWdifferencesMAXDATE, because I would also like to know the the amount of rows between the last row and the last time it occurred ONLY for the MAX date (2022-01-14 in this case). For this column, not all possible values in the column 'number' do exist. In that case the ROWdifferencesMAXDATE should be the amount of rows with this MAX(date) (in this case 3).

The other columns shouldn't be affected by this change. I have tried with WHERE MAX(date) etc, but then I get less records returned. Is this in a way possible?

Thank you so much in advance!

Expected outcome for this new column:

| number | ROWdifferencesMAXDATE |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 |
| 12 | 1 |
| 14 | 0 |
| 25 | 3 |
| 38 | 3 |
| 41 | 2 |
| 73 | 3 |

Comment: What is your expected output for this column?

Comment: Your description of `ROWdifferencesALWAYS` doesn't match what your query does.

Comment: You are right nick, I edited my post AND fiddle link. Also added the expected output. Thank you!

Comment: Do have any idea Nick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the answer to your previous question by adding a field which numbers the rows for each date, then when the number is present on that date you compute its position from that row number and the total number of rows on the maximum date value; otherwise its position is just the total number of rows on the maximum date.

```sql
WITH gdata AS (
  SELECT MAX(date) AS maxdate,
         COUNT(*) AS numrows
  FROM numbers
),
rowdata AS (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date, id) AS rn,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY id) AS drn,
         SUM(date = maxdate) OVER () AS numdate
  FROM numbers
  CROSS JOIN gdata
)
SELECT number,
       COUNT(*) AS occurrences,
       MIN(numrows - rn) AS ROWdifferencesALWAYS,
       MIN(CASE WHEN date = maxdate THEN numdate - drn
                ELSE numdate
           END) AS ROWdifferencesMAXDATE
FROM rowdata
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY number
```

Output:

```
number  occurrences ROWdifferencesALWAYS    ROWdifferencesMAXDATE
3       1           5                       3
12      1           1                       1
14      1           0                       0
25      1           7                       3
38      1           3                       3
41      2           2                       2
73      1           4                       3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=6cf9b0b5e01ba3f2a1ceab83da34ea9a)

Comment: This is brilliant Nick. Thank you so much! I have to admit that this is too complicated for me, but now I can go further with my PHP. Thanks again!

Comment: @Erik I'm glad it worked for you. Could you just clarify one thing, when you say "last" in "last time it occurred" (in the definition of `ROWdifferencesALWAYS`, do you mean last by `date` or last by `id`? If you mean last by `id`, you will probably need to change `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date, id) AS rn` to `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn`

Comment: To be honest, yesterday I have removed the row ROWdifferencesALWAYS, because I won't use it now I have ROWdifferencesMAXDATE. So I have cleaned up your queries a bit.

Comment: @Erik well that solves that problem then! :) I just wanted to make sure you were aware that the functionality might have been slightly different to your expectations.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me about this.

Comment: @Erik No worries - I just want to make sure you're happy with the answer.